# First time visit to run preloader script using cookie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, preloader

Although preloaders for websites are a controversial topic i have choosen to use one in this particular project.

The preloader is working fine. the problem being that is must only run on firstime visit

Heres what i have so far:

```
<? if (!isset($HTTP_COOKIE_VARS["visited"])) { echo "<script> 

$(window).load(function() { 
     $('#status').fadeOut(); 
     $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); 
     $('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});

       });


 </script>";

setcookie ("visited","Yes",time()+3600 * 24 * 10,'/', "siteurl.co.uk"); } ?>
```

The cookie is working however the preloader still runs everytime. Should i be using a if else statement? Any suggestions?

Comment: Just Use $_COOKIE http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$HTTP_* variables are deprecated**

**The reason that $HTTP_* vars don't work on many servers is because it is a PHP option to enable them.**

**Just Use $_COOKIE**

Comment: I have updated and re-tested, the cookie works fine, thanks for the heads up. however on the second visit the preloader doesnt leave the page.

Comment: here u have to check lasting of cookie life in your pho.ini file

Comment: sadly i dont really know much about PHP and the functions available.

Comment: Well its fixed the issue anyway. The second visit the preloader is always present because its the the cookie is working, which is not running the script to remove the preloader. Just a simple if else statement or even a CSS snippet will fix it :) Thanks a million anyway!